# Replace insert with rule in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I want to replace `INSERT` into a table with a PostgreSQL rule.

Here is my two tables:

```
Resource:
  uid (PK): UUID
  type (NOT_NULL): ENUM

SpecificResource:
  uid (PK, FK on resource.uid): UUID
  content (NOT_NULL): JSONB
```

I want any user to the database to be able to make insert/update/delete on `SpecificResource` directly without the need to insert/update/delete on Resource.

Here is my unsuccessful try that triggers an infinite recursion loop (indeed because I try to re-insert in `specific_resource` table with a `RULE (...) DO INSTEAD` :

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE RULE insert_specific_resource
AS ON INSERT TO specific_resource
DO INSTEAD (
    INSERT INTO resource (uid, type)
    VALUES (NEW.uid, 'SPECIFIC_RESOURCE');
    
    INSERT INTO specific_resource (uid)
    VALUES (new.uid)
);
```

Comment: Do you insist on using a rule? Maybe an `instead of` trigger?

Comment: A trigger would be excellent also, but it's far beyond my SQL knowledge.

Comment: I will suggest one to you. It is easier to comprehend.

Comment: @Stefanov.sm the following trigger works well for `resource` table. However, it does not insert anything in `specific_resource` table on `INSERT INTO specific_resource ...`

`CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_specific_resource()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS 
$BODY$
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO resource(uid, type)
 VALUES (uid, 'SPECIFIC_RESOURCE');
 RETURN NEW;
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER add_dashboard
BEFORE INSERT ON dashboard
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE add_specific_resource();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
create or replace function specific_resource_tf()
returns trigger language plpgsql as
$$
begin
 insert into resource(uid, type) VALUES (new.uid, 'SPECIFIC_RESOURCE');
 return new;
end;
$$;

create trigger specific_resource_t 
before insert on specific_resource
for each row
execute procedure specific_resource_tf();
```

Explanation

After creating trigger `specific_resource_t` it will be executed before each insert in table `specific_resource`. The trigger invokes function `specific_resource_tf` which does what your rule was intended to - inserts a record into `resource` before proceeding with the insert in table `specific_resource`.

**Illustration** (with temporary tables and function)

```sql
-- drop table if exists specific_resource; drop table if exists resource;
create temp table resource (uid integer primary key, type text);
create temp table specific_resource (uid integer references resource(uid), content JSONB);  

create or replace function pg_temp.specific_resource_tf()
returns trigger language plpgsql as $$
begin
 insert into resource(uid, type) VALUES (new.uid, 'SPECIFIC_RESOURCE');
 return new;
end;
$$;

create trigger specific_resource_t 
before insert on specific_resource
for each row execute procedure pg_temp.specific_resource_tf();

insert into specific_resource values (22, '"test"');
-- does insert in both tables
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It does not insert any row in `specific_resource` when I execute `INSERT INTO specific_resource (uid, content) VALUES ('an_uuid', '"test'")`

Comment: I do not believe that. Any error message?

Comment: Seems the syntax is wrong in pgadmin : `ERROR:  syntax error at or near ";"` for the last character. If I add parenthesis it works, but I guess it's not calling the function, trying to define it instead... But still add a row in `resource` and not `specific_resource`. Weird

Comment: My omission. Missed `()` in the end of `create trigger` statement. Fixed in the answer.

Comment: Sure :) Still, it inserts correctly in `resource` but not `specific_resource`..

Comment: I just tested it and it works as expected. Please note that the trigger is `before insert` on `specific_resource` and not on `dashboard`. It can be done as an `instead of insert` trigger on `dashboard` if it is a view but the trigger function will be slightly different.

Comment: `dashboard` was a typo from my part. I'm still getting no row inserted in `specific_resource`... I will post a new answer will my code.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_specific_plus_resource()
RETURNS TRIGGER LANGUAGE PLPGSQL AS 
$$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO resource(uid, type)
    VALUES (uid, 'SPECIFIC');
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER add_specific_resource
BEFORE INSERT ON specific_resource
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE add_specific_plus_resource();
```

The following `INSERT` works well to add a row into `resource` but not into `specific_resource`.

```sql
INSERT INTO specific_resource(uid, content)
VALUES ('123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174000', '"test"');
```

Comment: Pls. note that `OR REPLACE` is illegal for `create trigger`

Comment: @Stefanov.sm You nailed it, it works like a charm, thanks a lot !